# Redirect 301 in htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following urls to redirect to /rental-properties. Somehow they dont redirect properly.

```
Redirect 301 /Residential_Property/Auckland/Auckland_City/Avondale/Wingate_St/AVO224920 /rental-properties/
Redirect 301 /Residential_Property/Auckland/Auckland_City/Mount_Albert/Tyburnia_Ave/MYA20742 /rental-properties/
```

The first one redirects to

```
/rental-properties//Auckland/Auckland_City/Avondale/Wingate_St/AVO224920
```

instead of

```
/rental-properties/
```

Please help me on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Better you use `RedirectMatch` for targeted URLs like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Residential_Property/Auckland/Auckland_City/Avondale/Wingate_St/AVO224920/?$ /rental-properties/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Residential_Property/Auckland/Auckland_City/Mount_Albert/Tyburnia_Ave/MYA20742/?$ /rental-properties/
```